# Salesforce integration of quip (Free trial)

Tags: lightning, document, setup, quip, sales

Hello i want to integrate Quip in a salesforce sandbox to create a Proof of concept for a client. I created a quip domain with the free trial. Than in the domain i linked it to my salesforce sandbox. What i want to do is to have a Document componenet in the opportunity page, that refers to a quip document.

Unfortunatly i can't setup Salesforce anywhere (Quip) since i don't have acess to the Admin console of quip.
[image]

Do i have to buy the license to be a Quip Admin? or can i do something else so i cant make my demo?
[image]

Thanks you